# jquery- check if fields on form are not empty

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a couple of select elements and input fields....I can do a series of `if` statements to check, but I was curious if there was a master function that looks at the DOM and sees if there are values in data elements?

Thanks

Comment: It seems you're looking for form validation plugins.

Comment: there is a function that does that?

Comment: Not a function, a separate js file named as [jQuery Validation Plugin](http://jqueryvalidation.org/)

Comment: What's a 'data element'?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add a class called required_check and iterate through them with jquery

```
// target the proper elements and loop through them
$('.required_check').each(function(){

    //check the value of currently targeted element
    if($(this).val() == ''){

        // run code if field is empty
        alert($(this).attr('name')+' cannot be empty!');
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <style>

  td { text-align:center; }
  </style>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <table border="1">
    <tr><td>TD #0</td><td></td></tr>
    <tr><td>TD #2</td><td></td></tr>

    <tr><td></td><td>TD#5</td></tr>
  </table>
<script>$("td:empty").text("empty!").css('background', 'rgb(255,220,200)');</script>

</body>
</html>
```

btw you can simply use required attributes of the form elements

example `<input type="text" required="required">`

Comment: This only works for HTML5 compatible browsers and cannot be effectively relied on yet.

Comment: yeah I know, but the fact of required field is that all the modern and major browsers except older versions of IE etc are supporting HTML5. Take a look here..
 
http://blog.deepbluesky.com/blog/-/browser-support-for-css3-and-html5_72/

Comment: It should still be used responsibly in relation to the actual browsers that do visit your website. My website receives 60% IE8 users still. If even 5% get past your validation because they are on an old browser then you have still failed the task at hand.

Comment: Yeah I agree and that is why tags like
`<!--[if lte IE 6]>
<![endif]-->`
and 
prefix like **-webkit-**, **-moz-**, **-ms-**, **-o-** exist to help you make your site browser compatible. It is the standard practice to do so. By the way IE is 2nd most popular browser of the world...

Comment: Plus to let only HTML to handle all the checks is very bad practice, checks should be placed in javascript and PHP as well to decrease the probability of failure on demand value.. :)

Comment: Yes, server-side validation is always essential, but to avoid a broken user experience I prefer not to create specialized code for handling different browsers, very messy and annoying/difficult to maintain. Why avoid harnessing the power of jQuery?

Comment: Yeah why not, javascript is a powerful tool in regard to client side scripting and it will run on any browser with javascript enabled, but you need css to style your site and in that scenario you'll have to write specialized code for browsers, by the way Dreamweaver is very powerful and handles all that messy coding with specialized tags part for us so no worries.

Comment: CSS? "required" is an attribute of an element not a style.

Comment: i wasn't talking about **required** any more, please read my commenr again I said **but you need css to style your site and in that scenario you'll have to write specialized code for browsers**, you can see in my answer I have written **attribute of an element not CSS**